# C++ programming candidate function not viable

Tags: c++, priority-queue, functor

I am trying to make a priority queue which top most element contains the smallest integer. I made a function object for comparison. Everything is going well but, whenever I try to print out the top most element  `std::cout<<pq.top<<std::endl` I get an error that says:

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const value_type' (aka 'const Foo') to
  'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
basic_ostream& operator<<(const void* __p);
```

I am really new to programming so, I really don't know what to do.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue> 
#include <vector>


class Foo
{
public:
  int data;
  Foo(int data): data(data) {}
};

class Compare
{
public:
    int operator() (Foo dat1, Foo dat2)
    {
      if( dat1.data < dat2.data )
        return dat1.data;
      else return dat2.data;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::priority_queue<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, Compare> pq;

  pq.push(5);
  pq.push(7);
  pq.push(1);
  pq.push(2);
  pq.push(3);

  std::cout << pq.top() << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the end of your sentence "but whenaver I try..:" what happens then? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never defined a way to output a `Foo`.  You can use

```
std::cout << pq.top().data << std::endl;
```

Or you can overload the `operator<<` for `Foo` to output it like

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int data;
    Foo(int data) : data(data) {}
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo & f)
    {
        return os << f.data;
    }
};
```

You also have an issue with your comparision function.  The comparison function should return `true` if `dat1.data > dat2.data` in order to get the smallest element to the top.  With that you should change it to:

```
bool operator() (const Foo& dat1, const Foo& dat2)
{
  return dat1.data > dat2.data;
}
```

Comment: Also, I would prefer to have the bool operator() taking const references to Foo (`const Foo &`).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout << pq.top() << std::endl;
```

The call `pq.top()` in the above line returns a Foo object, which your program does not know to print. So that generates the error. By using `&pq.top()` you can print the address of the object, but since this is not the case you want to do right now, you can use `pq.top().data` to access the data item and print it.